# Arduino error when compiling

Tags: arduino-uno

When this code is uploaded I get an "Error Compiling". Any help is very much appreciated.

```c
#include <MeetAndroid.h>
#define supplyVolts 6
#define motorVolts 5
#define baudRate 57600
// If you are using a General Bluetooth adapter (available on buildcircuit.net), then, it works with 9600bps baud rate
MeetAndroid phone;
int left = 255; // midpoint
int right = 255;
int pwmLeftPin = 3;  1 int pwmRightPin = 11;
int directionLeftPin = 12;
int directionRightPin = 13;
void setup() {
  pinMode(pwmLeftPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pwmRightPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(directionLeftPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(directionRightPin, OUTPUT);
  setMotors();
  // use the baud rate your bluetooth module is configured to
  Serial.begin(baudRate);
  phone.registerFunction(setLeft, 'l');
  phone.registerFunction(setRight, 'r');
}

void loop() {
  phone.receive();
}

void setLeft(byte ignore, byte count) {
  int value = phone.getInt();
  left = value;
  setMotors();
}

void setRight(byte ignore, byte count) {
  int value = phone.getInt();
  right = value;
  setMotors();
}

void setMotors() {
  int vLeft = abs(left - 255) * motorVolts / supplyVolts;
  int vRight = abs(right - 255) * motorVolts / supplyVolts;
  int dLeft = (left > 255);
  int dRight = (right > 255);
  if (vLeft < 50) {
    vLeft = 0;
  }
  if (vRight < 50) {
    vRight = 0;
  }
  analogWrite(pwmLeftPin, vLeft);
  analogWrite(pwmRightPin, vRight);
  digitalWrite(directionLeftPin, dLeft);
  digitalWrite(directionRightPin, dRight);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Arduino Stack Exchange. We hope you find this site useful. In future posts, please format the code using the code formatting markdown (four leading spaces). For help see [Markdown help](http://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help). You should be able to do this by selecting the code and pressing `Ctrl+K` to have your browser do this for you. On this occasion I see that @jwpat7 has done it for you.

Comment: Where did you get the MeetAndroid library from? It's hard to reproduce your issue if we have to guess at where the libraries are to be found.

Comment: http://www.amarino-toolkit.net/index.php/download.html

Answer (score 4):

Take a close look at this line. The compiler will not like that as it does not have the right syntax.

```
int pwmLeftPin = 3;  1 int pwmRightPin = 11;
```

Change it to:

```
int pwmLeftPin = 3;
int pwmRightPin = 11;
```

This should at least remove the first issue with your code.

Cheers!

Comment: @Tom Evans if mikael's answer worked, you should press the check mark next to his answer to reward him with some reputation.